# Technique to Equalize Histogram Bin size and Ks Density Curve Bandwidth

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, time-series, signal-processing, sampling

I have also asked the query few days before because the clarification was vague so that's why I am uploading a query with updated views.Link is as follows.
[Updated :Technique used to control Step sizes (Quantization levels) of signals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45796290/technique-used-to-control-step-sizes-of-signals-and-controlling-size-of-ks-densi)

I am explaining example data here because it is not possible for me to mention my original data.

I have plotted a histogram curve along with ks density.

I have placed bin size =10 and bandwidth of ks Density curve to be 0.08.

Actually I want to analyze the values based on data from Histfit (by applying 3 modal technique.) and Ks density curve.

**Example Code:**

```
 x = rand([1 50])
 figure(1)
 histfit(x,10)
 hold on 
 % [f,xi] = ksdensity(x);
 [f,xi,bw] = ksdensity(x,'width',0.08);
 plot(xi,f);
 hold off
```

Question:

Is it possible that I make the bin size and Bandwidth of Ks density curve same to visualize the results on same standards?

In simple words is bin size 10 equals to 0.08 bandwidth from Ks density curve.

Or how to make bin size and bandwidth equal to visualize the results on same standards.

[image]

Comment: Why have you asked a self-duplicate (which is not appropriate on SO and will probably be closed as such), instead of having updated your previous question?

Comment: Actually that is not a self duplicate I made a new qurrey because the previous qurrey contains 2 questions.

Comment: 2 questions in a single post is not allowed either, as that's "Too broad", since every question should get a self-contained answer. Please edit both posts to contain only *one* question per post and don't post self-duplicates in the future. (Yes, it's a self duplicate, although only of the latter half)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Technique used to control Step sizes of signals and controlling size of ks density bandwidth and bin size of Histogram in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45796290/technique-used-to-control-step-sizes-of-signals-and-controlling-size-of-ks-densi)

Comment: Adriaan I have updated both the qurries and now they are newand differnt from each other.